# Add a nested json to mongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I want to insert to a mongodb collection a nested json file. The template of file is the following:

```
 {"username": name,
  "data"{

    "id":id
    "Date":date
    "text":text 
 }
 }
```

EDIT: I want to add the above json file to a mongo collection. I want to add the first field username, in the first loop (for files in onlyfiles) and concatenate all the rows information in the second loop(for row in myscv)

```
  onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ] // list of csv files(text)
  for files in onlyfiles:
    name = files.split('_') // name of the file also the username
    mycsv = csv.reader(open(mypath+files)) // read the file
    my_data = {"username": name[0],
                "data":{}
          } //add the first fields to json 
    for row in mycsv: // for every line in csv file 

            '_id':row[0], //concatenate to my_data
            'Date':row[1],
            'text':row[2] 
       }
     } // concatenate to my_data
     collection.insert(my_data)
```

I want data to have as line every csv file contains. How can I do so?

EDIT: I manage to do the nested json in loops with the following code:

```
for files in onlyfiles:
  name = files.split('_')
  mycsv = csv.reader(open(mypath+files))
  my_data = {"username": name[0],
                "tweets":[]
          }
  for row in mycsv:
     text = row[2]
     data = {
            "_id":row[0],
            "Date":row[1],
            "text":row[2]       
     }
my_data["tweets"].append(data) //my_data["tweets"].append(data)

print my_data
```

However as it is right now, it is just add the last row from csv to "tweets" field. How can I concatenate all the rows to tweets field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution in order to create a nested json inside two for-loops. My code is look like:

```
for files in onlyfiles:
  name = files.split('_')
  mycsv = csv.reader(open(mypath+files))
  my_data = {"username": name[0],
                "tweets":[]
          }
  tweets = []
  for row in mycsv:
        text = row[2]
        data = {
                "_id":row[0],
                "Date":row[1],
                "text":row[2]       
        }   
    tweets.append(data)
  my_data["tweets"].append(tweets)       
  collection.insert(my_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line has incorrect syntax.

collection.insert(**{"username":name[0]}**,{'_id':row[0], 'Date':row[1], 'text': row[2]})

only the username part will be inserted, the other parameter will not be.

Your template json has no key for the second data :

```
 {"username": name
 {
     'id':id,
     'Date':date,
     'text':text 
 }
 }
```

should be something like :

```
 my_data = {"username": name,
  "data":{
     'id':id,
     'Date':date,
     'text':text 
 }
 } 

 collection.insert(my_data)
```

Comment: Ok but this is not a nested json file.

Comment: Ok, however I couldnt figure how can I overcome syntax error in json template. Moreover, in second line.

Comment: Is possible to create the first field username in first loop, and add the data field in the second loop?

Answer (score -2):

```
"abc": [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed 
    }],
```